# Char Pointer allocation within a function - Segmentaion fault

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to allocate memory to a char pointer inside a function. But I get a segmentation fault inside the function in the `for cycle at i=1`. For `i=0`it allocates memory. I am struggling to get this solved. Maybe other 'eyes' can see what is wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void AllocateDeallocate(int, int, int, char***);

int main(void)
{
    char** header1;
    char** header2;
    AllocateDeallocate(1,3,40,&header1);

    return 0;
}

void AllocateDeallocate(int iopt, int nStr, int StrLen, char*** Str)
{
    int i;
    switch (iopt)
    {
    case 1:
        if (NULL == Str)
        {           
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(*Str == NULL)
        {
            *Str = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*nStr);          
            if (*Str== NULL)
            {
                puts("Memory allocation failed.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }       
        }
        for(i = 0 ; i< nStr;i++)
        {   
            printf("String %d allocation\n",i); 
            *Str[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(StrLen+1));
            if (*Str[i] == NULL)
            {
                puts("Memory allocation failed.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for( i = 0; i<nStr; i++)
        {
            free(*Str[i]);
        }
        free(*Str);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Wrong Option");
    }
}
```

Comment: All `*Str[i]` should be `(*Str)[i]`.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition. And you should not cast the return value from `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: Your `AllocateDeallocate` function looks at `*Str` to compare it with `NULL` -- but the caller never gave `header1` a value, so you're looking at garbage.

Comment: Sidenote: Three levels of indirection `char*** Str` seems excessive. You might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: The design to have a single function doing both allocation and deallocation seems flawed to me. It will make the code harder to read and maintain, especially with the use of [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: Being a three-star C programmer is not a compliment. something like `char ***` in an interface is a clear signal something went wrong.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310798/multidimensional-array-on-the-heap-c/35313096#35313096).

Comment: @Olaf : Being a Fortran programmer I started to learn C a few time ago. So, I am interested on learning the core of C/C++. And that means doing the things ugly sometimes.

Comment: @PedroR.: You first have to understand there is no language C/C++. So you first should decise which of the two **different** languages C or C++ you want to learn. Then pick a good book about **modern** C (i.e. C99, better the current standard C11) or C++ (C++11 at least).

Comment: @Olaf: I was trying to say that I am learning `C` and then `C++`. Just it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the function `AllocateDeallocate` the variable `header1` is not initialized. That means inside the function `*Str` haven an *indeterminate* value (and will be seemingly random).

When you then use `*Str` (for example in `*Str == NULL`) that will lead to problems (as the value is most likely *not* equal to `NULL`).

The simple solution? Initialize the variables in the `main` function:

```
char** header1 = NULL;
char** header2 = NULL;
```

---

Once you fix the above problem you have others. Like when you do `*Str[i]`. Due to [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) rules it's equal to `*(Str[i])` which is *not* what you want. You need to explicitly use parentheses to have `(*Str)[i]`.

---

Both the above problems will lead to *undefined behavior* and are likely causes for crashes.

Comment: Solved. I forgot that.